# passing multiple vars as params to a macro

Tags: nunjucks

I would need some help to solve this.
My plan is to create a "universal" macro that is able to call all other macros.
It already works when the macro it wants to call just has 1 param.

This is my macro with 2 params

```
{% macro render(type,txt="Button to push") %}
```

This is the macro I want to call that then calls the other macro

```
{% macro render(path,vars) %}
{% import "partials/"+path+".nunjucks" as ce %}
{{ ce.render(vars) }}
```

and the vars looks like this right now:

```
{% set vars = [{ var: "type='primary'"}, { var: "text='Primary'" }] %}
```

so, in the end, I want to call the macro

```
ce.render(type="Primary",txt="Primary")
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Try to avoid to use `var` because it's a reserved word. P.S. I don't understand what do you need exactly. `render(type="Primary",txt="Primary")` a same to `render("Primary", "Primary")`

Comment: I want to be able to call a macro that is able to call all other macros I have in my project. the number of params of the macros are from 1 to 10.

I have a macro that is able to build a button. this macro has two params, class and text.
I also have a macro that is able to build an image and this has 3 params, class, width, height.

and I have a "main" macro (macro-container) that I want to call to create a button and an image.

so I need to call my macro-container and pass infos to get button macro with the 2 params or the image macro with 3 params.

hope this helps @AikonMogwai

Comment: As I understood, the main macro has next definition `render(macroName, arg1, arg2, arg3, ...) `. So, the problem is how to pass `arg1, arg2, ...` to macro defined by macroName. There are two ways: 1. Always pass 3+ args e.g. `ce.render(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4)`. The order of args is fixed. 2. Rewrite child macros and pass all vars as object with arg-keys e.g. `{type: 'primary', txt: 'MyButton'}`. P.S. Recommended file extension is `.njk`, not `.nunjucks`.